# program seperates audio, videos and save them by making folders seperately but it is giving error when i run again that folder already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, shutil

this program is seperating different files i.e. audio, video and document and saves them seperately by making different folders i.e. audioFiles, videoFiles, documentFiles here is the code

```
import os, shutil 
dict_extensions = {
    'audio_extensions' : ('.mp3', '.m4a', '.wav', '.flac'),
    'video_extensions' : ('.mp4', '.mkv', '.MKV', '.flv', '.mpeg'),
    'document_extensions' : ('.doc', '.pdf', '.txt'),
}


folderpath = input('enter folder path : ')

def file_finder(folder_path, file_extensions):
    # files = []
    # for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    #     for extension in file_extensions:
    #         if file.endswith(extension):
    #             files.append(file)
    # return files
    return [file for file in os.listdir(folder_path) for extension in file_extensions if file.endswith(extension)]
for extension_type, extension_tuple in dict_extensions.items():
    folder_name = extension_type.split('_')[0] + ' Files'
    folder_path = os.path.join(folderpath, folder_name)
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
    for item in file_finder(folderpath, extension_tuple):
        item_path = os.path.join(folderpath,item)
        item_new_path = os.path.join(folder_path,item)
        shutil.move(item_path,item_new_path)
    if os.listdir(folder_path)==[]:
        os.rmdir(folder_path)
```

also it will not create the folder when file related to it doesn't exist. but when i rerun it it gives error that folder already exists. so i tried to solve this problem by if else statement but it is still giving the same error. here is the code after small changes:-

```
import os, shutil
dict_extensions = {
    'audio_extensions' : ('.mp3', '.m4a', '.wav', '.flac'),
    'video_extensions' : ('.mp4', '.mkv', '.MKV', '.flv', '.mpeg','.MTS'),
    'document_extensions' : ('.doc', '.pdf', '.txt','.docx'),
}


folderpath = input('enter folder path : ')

def file_finder(folder_path, file_extensions):
    # files = []
    # for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    #     for extension in file_extensions:
    #         if file.endswith(extension):
    #             files.append(file)
    # return files
    return [file for file in os.listdir(folder_path) for extension in file_extensions if file.endswith(extension)]

# print(file_finder(folderpath, video_extensions))
for extension_type, extension_tuple in dict_extensions.items():
    if os.path.exists(extension_type.split('_')[0] + 'Files'):
        path=os.path.join(folderpath,extension_type.split('_')[0] + 'Files')
        for item in file_finder(folderpath, extension_tuple):
            item_path = os.path.join(folderpath,item)
            item_new_path = os.path.join(path,item)
            shutil.move(item_path,item_new_path)
    else:
        folder_name = extension_type.split('_')[0] + 'Files'
        folder_path = os.path.join(folderpath, folder_name)
        os.mkdir(folder_path)
        for item in file_finder(folderpath, extension_tuple):
            item_path = os.path.join(folderpath,item)
            item_new_path = os.path.join(folder_path,item)
            shutil.move(item_path,item_new_path)
    if os.listdir(folder_path)==[]:
        os.rmdir(folder_path)
```

and the error is

```
 python first_project_edited.py
enter folder path : E:\testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first_project_edited.py", line 33, in <module>
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'E:\\testing\\audioFiles'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs:https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir

> If the directory already exists, FileExistsError is raised.

Try:

```
os.makedirs(folder_path,exist_ok = True)
```

or:

```
if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, shutil


dict_extensions = {
    'audio_extensions' : ('.mp3', '.m4a', '.wav', '.flac'),
    'video_extensions' : ('.mp4', '.mkv', '.MKV', '.flv', '.mpeg'),
    'document_extensions' : ('.doc', '.pdf', '.txt'),
}


folderpath = input('enter folder path : ')

def file_finder(folder_path, file_extensions):
    # files = []
    # for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    #     for extension in file_extensions:
    #         if file.endswith(extension):
    #             files.append(file)
    # return files
    return [file for file in os.listdir(folder_path) for extension in file_extensions if file.endswith(extension)]

for extension_type, extension_tuple in dict_extensions.items():
    folder_name = extension_type.split('_')[0] + ' Files'
    folder_path = os.path.join(folderpath, folder_name)
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.mkdir(folder_path)
    for item in file_finder(folderpath, extension_tuple):
        item_path = os.path.join(folderpath,item)
        item_new_path = os.path.join(folder_path,item)
        shutil.move(item_path,item_new_path)
    if os.listdir(folder_path)==[]:
        os.rmdir(folder_path)
```

finally got the complete solution. thank u so much @Danyang :)